# How to connect to mysql with go?

Tags: mysql, go

I have been trying to connect mysql with go, but i can seem to succeed. I'm just trying to get a value from table and set it to variable and print it. What i'm missing maybe just something obvious

this is from the database called bankdata

```
mysql> select * from accounts ;
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
| id | username | email           | facebook | twitter |
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
|  1 | user1    | email1@mail.com | userfb1  | NULL    |
|  2 | user2    | email2@mail.com | NULL     | NULL    |
|  3 | user3    | email3@mail.com | NULL     | NULL    |
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
```

there's two drivers that i used, and i can seem to understand what wrong with both of them

using [go-sql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql)

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/Go-SQL-Driver/MySQL"
    "log"
)

const (
    DB_HOST = "tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)"
    DB_NAME = "bankdata"
    DB_USER = /*"root"*/ "bankadmin"
    DB_PASS = /*""*/ "1234"
)

func main() {
    dsn := DB_USER + ":" + DB_PASS + "@" + DB_HOST + "/" + DB_NAME + "?charset=utf8"
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    var str string
    q := "select username from bankadmin.accounts where id = 1"
    err = db.QueryRow(q).Scan(&str)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(str)
}
```

this returns

```
D:\_>go run dbtest.go
2013/03/29 13:14:11 Error 1045: Access denied for user 'bankadmin'@'localhost'
(using password: YES)
exit status 1
```

the password is actually right, for the both user root and bankadmin, and the mysql in running in port 3306. But then again, if i change the DB_HOST to "tcp(127.0.0.1:3000)" or change the 127.0.0.1 to localhost, it gave me the same error.

using [mymysql driver](https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql)

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"
    "log"
    "strconv"
)

const (
    DB_HOST = "tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)"
    DB_NAME = "bankdata"
    DB_USER = "bankadmin"
    DB_PASS = "1234"
)

type User struct {
    Id       int    
    Username string 
    Email    string 
    Facebook string
}

func OpenDB() *sql.DB {
    db, err := sql.Open("mymysql", fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/%s", DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return db
}

func UserById(id int) *User {
    db := OpenDB()
    defer db.Close()
    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT id, username, email FROM accounts WHERE id=?", id)
    user := new(User)
    row.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Username, &user.Email, &user.Facebook)
    return user
}

func main() {
    db := OpenDB()
    defer db.Close()
    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT id, username, email, facebook FROM accounts WHERE id=2")
    user := new(User)
    row.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Username, &user.Email, &user.Facebook)
    fmt.Println("id    : " + strconv.Itoa(user.Id) + "\nname  : " + user.Username + "\nemail : \n" + user.Email)

}
```

this returns:

```
D:\_>go run dbtest.go
id    : 0
name  :
email :
```

it looks like both the id and the strings is empty, like it's never received any values from row.Scan function. And i don't know how to make sure that they are connected even though they didn't give me the same error as the previous driver

Oh, and i'm using Windows 7, MySQL 5.5.8 that comes with WAMP.

If i made any mistake in this post, pardon me. This is my first post.

Comment: make sure your user is bankadmin and password is 1234

Comment: this is what's written on mysql cmd

`mysql> drop database if exists bankdata;`
`Query OK, 1 row affected (1.28 sec)`

`mysql> create database bankdata;`
`Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)`

`mysql> grant all privileges on bankdata.* to 'bankadmin'@'localhost' identified by '1234';`
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)`

`mysql> flush privileges;`
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)`

`mysql> use bankdata;`
`Database changed`

Comment: Is the Go-MySQL-Driver up to date?
It  might be this bug: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/35
Otherwise, like Baron Schwartz said: 
`This is a really common problem with MySQL in general. There's probably a .01% chance this is a problem in the driver. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html and look especially at the portions that discuss what happens when you have default privileges in the privilege tables. In your case you probably have a mismatch between the hostname defined for the user in the privileges table, and the hostname used for authentication.`

Comment: And please note, that the package path changed to `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` (all lowercase)

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't your go code the problem is you mysql configuration. You may have the right username and password but you probably haven't authorized that user to connect to the database using tcp.

Comment: how to do the configuration?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html has some of the many causes of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As mentioned by @Jeremy wall, the problem was with the connection string. The user name i used is wrong. To configure the settings, 
1. Go to "Server" option
2. Select Manage Server Connections
3. select Connections section
4. Click store in keychain button in password section and enter new password

you are all set. now try the test connection button. It worked for me when i tried to access the db from GO program.